# Need to find upgrade to Cirrus Logic 5434

Tags: memory, motherboard, integrated-graphics

"The V12LC-I ships with the Cirrus 5430/5434 VGA PCI accelerator on-board. It supports up to 2 MB video memory for a resolution up to 1024x768x256, non-interlaced. Large video memory allows you to display higher resolutions and more colors*. The system board comes with 1 MB onboard, upgradable to 2 MB." Where can I buy an upgrade?

[image]

The brown squares on the right are built into my motherboard and must be filled.

Comment: built into the motherboard? or is this an add-on (PCI) card as shown in the picture?  if that isn't an exact picture of your hardware, we will not be able to identify specific components.

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/73791/need-to-find-upgrade-to-cirrus-logic-5434

Comment: You didn't need to ask the question again, it was migrated from SO - http://superuser.com/questions/73934/need-to-find-upgrade-to-cirrus-logic-5434 - also if you associate your accounts you'll regain ownership of the other question

Answer (score 1):

The video memory on the Cirrus Logic 5434 can be upgraded to 2MB, by using two **512K X 8-70ns SOJ DRAM** chips.

where to buy? beats me! this stuff is well over 15 years old. IIRC, the card was made in the early 1990ies. :)

Comment: if he needs another 1mb, 2x 256k won't quite get there.  he needs 2x 512kb chips, and would need to match up the packages.  (just from counting pins, this is a 44-pin package and the socket on the board pictured appears to be take a 20-pin or a 40-pin package, depending on which holes are counted.)

Comment: right, these are 20-DIP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not programming related, so the right place to ask would be superuser.com.

The picture doesn't show a motherboard, this is a PCI graphis card. What you need would be a pair of 256kx8 DRAM chips, 45 ns if I read it right. Since the chips you need are long out of production, you can only hope to find them at them at ebay or something similar. Note that replacing the whole graphics card is probably cheaper and a lot safer and easier.